# 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'form' of undefined or null reference

Tags: jquery, validation

its being a while i am finding the solution for this please help me with it
i am getting a
***error:0x800a138f - JavaScript run-time error: Unable to get property 'form' of undefined or null reference***:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  debugger;
  $("#CreateForm").validate({
    rules: {
      Certificeringscode: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      Certificeringscode: {
        required: "Please Enter Certificeringscode"
      }
    }
  });

  $('#CertificeringcreateEditBtn').on('click', function() {
    debugger;
    var isValid = $("#CreateForm").valid();
    var Certificeringsnummer = $("#Certificeringsnummer").val();
    var Certificeringscode = $("#Certificeringscode").val();
    var isSuccess = -1;

    if (!isvalid) {
      return false;
    } else {
      var Certificering = {
        "Certificeringsnummer": Certificeringsnummer,
        "Certificeringscode": Certificeringscode,
      };
      $.ajax({
        // HomeController and InsertData method
        url: "@Url.Action("CreateEdit ", " Certificering ", new { Area = " Admin " })",

        data: JSON.stringify(Certificering),
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

        success: function(result) {
          window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "MasterList", new { Area = "Admin", Id ="3"})';

          isSuccess = 1;


        },

        error: function(result) {
          //debugger;
          alert("Something went wrong, please try again");
        }
      }).done(function() {
        if (isSuccess == "1") {
          // Successfully Deleted
          $("#List").dialog('close');
          alert("Record Saved Successfully");
          // refresh the page
        } else { // Data Error
          alert("Error. Please, check the data");
        }

      });
    }
  });
  $("#CancelEditBtn").click(function(e) {
    $("#List").dialog('close');
  });

  $('form input').on('keypress', function(e) {
    return e.which !== 13;
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: which line is causing the error?

Comment: Your success function navigates to Admin/MasterList/Index/. But you also have .done function. But your main issue is that your js cannot find the form

Comment: i want to add a class directly to text box field but when i do so and when i call it using  $("#CreateForm").validate() on document.ready it always navigates to something went wrong?